# <br> larger break than usual?

Tags: css, html, user-interface

This hasn't been a problem in the past, I don't know what has happened, but the 
 element in my footer separates the text by like, 10px's. Wondering if I have some CSS or a tag I'm not aware of?

Here is my code:

```css
.contentFake {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 200px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #1A1A1A;
  display: block;
}

.footerContent {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='contentFake'>
  <div class='footerContent'>
    <p>
      <font face="Helvetica" size="2" color="white">
        <font size="5" face="Indie Flower"><strong>THIS IS FOOTER</strong></font> <br />
        <a href="index.html">Home</a><br />
        <a href="BLOG.html">Blog </a><br />
        <a href="PHOTOS.html">Photo Feed </a><br />
        <a href="VLOGS.html">Vlogs </a><br />
        <a href="VIDEO.html">Farewell </a><br />
        <a href="#">BACK TO TOP </a><br /> © Jack Champions FOOTER All Rights Reserved 2017</font>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gu1pdh5a/

The code  you run direct here, is the code I wish to see, yet on mine it turns up like this?

[image: br code]

Comment: provide a fiddle

Comment: You need to demonstrate what you are expecting to see vs what you have - There is nothing wrong with your html and css.

Comment: I'm sorry... what is a fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle is a codedemonstration where you produce the error. SOF has its own or you could use e.g. http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @JackChampion did you fixed it ?

Comment: @edisoni.1337 yes, I did end up fixing it, yet I don't know how, thats why I left the question up and unanswered, I still don't know what happened :/

Answer (score 2):

From your image i see that there is a lot of space. I will give you some fixes for that and then you can try which is the right one for you.

Firstly that space is caused by `<br>` or by `<a>` so lets remove padding and margin for each one

```
.footerContent br{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

This one does the same for the `<a>` element

```
.footerContent a{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gu1pdh5a/1/) where i removed `<br>` tags and just showing `<a>` as block one in each line and using margin.

And here is another [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gu1pdh5a/3/) using `<ul>` (This is better and easier to manage) .

Answer (score 1):

Your `<p>` element has default margins (top and bottom), so just overwrite them with new styles for `p` elements like this for example `p {margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 1):

use  margin and padding instead of `<br>` tags.you can give padding top and bottom to the a tags.